# session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute a test case using cucumber selenium however I am getting the following error on running
npm test

```
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75
       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64)
         at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:529:15)
         at parseHttpResponse (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
         at doSend.then.response (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
     From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
         at Function.createSession (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
         at Function.createSession (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
         at createDriver (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
         at Builder.build (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:642:16)
         at new module.exports (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/runtime/chromeDriver.js:20:8)
         at getDriverInstance (/home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/runtime/world.js:54:22)
         at /home/harshs/Documents/Programming/GoogleSearch/node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/runtime/world.js:207:29
```

Earlier, the 2.41 version of chromedriver was installed, and I was getting the same error, so I updated the chromedriver to 2.46 version.
using
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
installs chrome version 76

I tried to search for other threads and what I could find was to try to update selenium-webdriver and I have no idea how to do that.

Please help.